# Why are the bits in bytes equally distributed?

Tags: linux

I took the first 1mil bits from a random video file, and then for each byte I mapped each bit to a bin, e.g.

```
c_b = ''.join(format(ord(b), '08b') for b in c)
bin1.append(c_b[0])
```

Then counted:

```
bin1_counted = Counter(bin1)
```

and the results were:

```
Counter({'0': 646491, '1': 603686})
Counter({'0': 642133, '1': 608044})
Counter({'0': 644298, '1': 605879})
Counter({'0': 641961, '1': 608216})
Counter({'0': 641778, '1': 608399})
Counter({'0': 640538, '1': 609639})
Counter({'0': 641531, '1': 608646})
```

It clearly shows an equal distribution. But I was hoping someone could explain to me why that is so, given my assumption that the first bit in every byte should have much more `0` than `1` because I'm thinking that it is probable that there should be some kind of bell distribution of every bytes' position, i.e. I was expecting the first/second bit of every byte to have much more `0` since characters can be represented before reaching 64?

Comment: What do you mean by "characters" in a video file?

Comment: If you were looking at text then maybe you'd see a pattern, but compressed video data wouldn't use the ASCII character set. It would make use of the full range of bits available to ensure that the output data doesn't just have "wasted" space.

Comment: I expected to see 8 results, there are 7. What am I missing?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I just missed copying the last row

Comment: @choroba this python lang reads it like that `ord(b), '08b') for b in c`. I have to `ord()` each next ?character?

Comment: @Mokubai that makes sense, but could you explain the `full range of bits available`? Doesn't encoder still write bytes?

Comment: @Tjorriemorrie Tonny has stated it better than I could in his answer.  That was what I was trying to get at.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not surprising given the type of data you are looking at.

A video-stream consists of very highly compressed data.
Looking at the raw bytes these appear as nearly perfect random data.
That is a basic property of high compressed (high entropy) data.

And nearly perfect random data has a nearly perfect random distribution of the bits, meaning every individual bit has an equal distribution.

If you do the same thing on a huge ASCII text file you will see that the most significant bit (2^7) will not appear at all (or only a few times at most) and a couple of others will appear with VERY high frequencies.
That is because ASCII has a very skewed distribution with the most used values clustered in a few small subsets within the 0..255 range.

Comment: Thanks, I probably should've known the high compression should cause that. Just wanted to be sure about it.